# Query IF col3 = close

Tags: google-sheets

How would I adjust this formula to assume Col4 is negative IF Col3 contains "close".

```
=QUERY(VSTACK(A2:D),"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4)
```

where Col2 is not null
group by Col1, Col2
label Col1 'Trade ID', Col2 'Asset', sum(Col4) 'Amount'")

Hopefully I provided enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=QUERY({A2:C,index(D2:D*if(C2:C="close",-1,1))},"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) 
where Col2 is not null group by Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Trade ID', Col2 'Asset', sum(Col4) 'Amount'")
```